# get value of member in structure dynamically

Tags: c++, data-structures, struct, structure

Here there is a structure:

```
struct date
 {
  int day;
  int month;
  int year;
 }frmt;
```

A structure is initialized and members are assigned values.
Now, I want to get value of a member using dynamic variable.

Generally we use frmt.day to get value of that member.
Now let std::string str1="day";
How can i get member value using str1?
Can I use str1.c_str()  ??

Comment: You have to do it manually with code. C++ has no reflection yet, but it might be added in C++20.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Sorry..I didn't understand..Can you please give an example

Comment: `if (str1 == "day") std::cout << frmt.day; else if (str1 == "month") std::cout << frmt.month; else blah blah`.

Comment: But in reality, I have many members included in that structure

Comment: Consider a map of `std::string` to `int date::*` member pointers. You'll of course have to populate that map yourself. You cannot address a member by it's name at runtime without adding extra machinery yourself.

Comment: You can generate said map of if-else-if chain using [x-macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) or Boost.Preprocessor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::map<std::string, int>` or `std::unordered_map<std::string, int>` for you simple struct in the example. In this case you should in all places in your code replace `frmt.day` with `frmt["day"]` and etc. Thus you can call `frmt[str1]`.

If a struct has members of various types, you could use `std::variant` instead of `int` (since C++17).

Comment: This is a possible workaround for the problem, but doesn't address the problem itself. And you lose the ability to address the members directly in constant time when which member to access doesn't depend on runtime information.

Comment: Sure, it is a workaround. As for to address member directly, OP could access map members (like in his example) by references, or even construct  struct of references like `struct simple { int& day; simple(int &day) day(day) {} };` simple frmt2(frmt["day"]);. It would not be POD but who knows how deeply OP wants to do it.

Comment: @S.M. thank you...I will try...its a generic implementation where I cannot do hard-coding of values or members